# How to properly use the sql NOT IN(..) Method?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do something called "PEOPLE YOU MAY KNOW IN YOUR SCHOOL THAT ARE NOT YOUR FRIENDS YET"

I will explain my basic logic behind my code first:

I am fetching users id (from main table -USERS) which are in the same school with the current loggin user and if i get at least 10 rows,

I then ask database questions to check (from friends table- FRIEND) if the current user is already friends with them (using their id)

contitions:
If current loggin user is friends with them some of them{
ask databse to select  (from main table- USERS) where id is not equal id in the friends table and school is equal to current loggin user school
}

Problem:
In my code, I am using the sql NOT IN(...) method and it return both the same id in the friend table numerous times and the ids  not in the friends table 
even though they these users  are not in the same school

My question is: How do I properly use the NOT IN() method to get the opposite of IN($user) method in my code  or what proper logic can i use to achieve this.

Please forgive me am asking much from you guys...I am a child to PHP and SQL

A practical code example would be much appreciated.
Thank you so much.

below is my code:

```
function somepeopleyoumayknow(){
global $dbc_conn, $IsLoggIn,$table_name,$friend_request_table,$friends_table ; 

$cu_school = getuser($IsLoggIn,'cell_group');

$peopleids= mysqli_query($dbc_conn,"SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE 
cell_group='$cu_school'  AND id !='$IsLoggIn' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
if(mysqli_num_rows($peopleids) > 0){
while($run_pids = mysqli_fetch_array($peopleids)){
$pid = $run_pids['id'];

//echo $pidd = $run_pids['id']."<br>";

//ckeck if you are already friends
$quer_check_friendship = mysqli_query($dbc_conn,"SELECT user_one,user_two FROM $friends_table
WHERE (user_one='$IsLoggIn' AND user_two IN($pid)) OR (user_one IN($pid) AND user_two='$IsLoggIn')");
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($quer_check_friendship);
if($nr > 0 ){ while($run_nr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($quer_check_friendship)){
    if($run_nr['user_one'] ==$IsLoggIn){
        $user = $run_nr['user_two'];
    }else{

    $user = $run_nr['user_one'];

    }



    $query_not_friend_with = mysqli_query($dbc_conn,"SELECT id FROM $table_name WHERE id NOT IN($user)  AND cell_group='$cu_school' ");
while($run_not_frnds_with = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_not_friend_with)){ echo "You are not friends with".$run_not_frnds_with['id']."<br>";}
}


}else{
    echo 'Not friends with them so do sothing here';

}

}






}



}
```

Comment: are you only troubling with `NOT IN`???

Comment: yes because it shows users ids that are both already in the friends table and its repeats numerously. please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Use of NOT IN**

MySQL NOT IN() makes sure that the expression proceeded does not have any of the values present in the arguments.

**Syntax**

```
expr NOT IN (value,...)
```

**Example:**

If you want to fetch the rows from the table book_mast which contain books not written in English or German, the following sql statement can be used.

```
$user = '1, 2, 3';
SELECT `id` FROM $table_name WHERE id NOT IN($user) AND cell_group='$cu_school'
```